# Monitor http request in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

how I can capture all http request in firefox addon. 
I am not able to find api example . 
can anybody tell me how firebug does it for net panel ?

I want to detect all http request and response in firebug.

Comment: Why not have a look at the Firebug source code?

Comment: I looked but there are lot of files.

Comment: is firebug-http-observer correct file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to the [gBrowser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load) global object, making sure to set usecapture to true. You could also [intercept the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers).